# Use of ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx (ImportExcel) to convert .xls to .xlsx

Tags: powershell

Trying to convert .xls file to .xlsx

by ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx function of ImportExcel module
https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/

Github documentation says

Thanks to Mikkel Nordberg. He contributed a ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx. To use it, Excel needs to be installed. The function converts the older Excel file format ending in .xls to the new format ending in .xlsx.

help ConvertTo-ExcelXls returns the following as syntax:
    ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx [-Path]  [-Force] []

So I am trying do it like:

```
ConvertTo-ExcelXls -path "C:\MyFolder\MyFile.xls"
```

but I am getting:
**ConvertTo-ExcelXls : The term 'ConvertTo-ExcelXls' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ ConvertTo-ExcelXls -path 'C:\MyFolder\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ConvertTo-ExcelXls:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

Comment: You mention `ConvertTo-ExcelXls` and `ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx` several times, seemingly interchangeably. Notice the trailing **x** on the second one there. Try using that and see if it works better.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thank you very much. Too late for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer is basically written in your question. The syntax is `ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx` but you invoked `ConvertTo-ExcelXls` which is not available in your shell (note the missing `x` at the end).

So here is the thing. Powershell adds `Get-` if it cannot resolve a command, so if you invoke `help`, it's actually `Get-Help`. `Get-Help` outputs any command that matches a part of your specified name. `Get-Help -Name Excel` would have given you the function as well (and probably some more). That's why you got help for `ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx` even though you looked up `ConvertTo-ExcelXls`. This makes it a littly bit tricky, but on the other hand, the help message was really helpful.